# Python Data Plot shown up in Spyder but not in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, spyder

I have the following code which can plot the graph in Spyder but not in Sublime Text 3 when running:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = "dt=1.out"

output = pd.read_csv(filename,sep=r'\s+')

plt.plot(output['time'].values, output['yexact'].values, 's-',label=r'yexact')
```

The problem is that in Spyder it works perfect and the graph shows.

However, in Sublime Text, the code is able to run but no graph shows up. The top bar of Sublime twinkles a second but no graph is generated. I'm thinking that the Sublime Python does not support  the graph of imported numerical data, because when I plot other data that is not imported from outside files, the graph in Sublime shows up and totally works.

Can anyone help me fix this problem to let this code show graph in Sublime Text 3?

Comment: I cannot attach image because of not enough reputation.

Comment: You probably need to add `plt.ion()` to your script to make it work in Sublime. The thing is: 1) Matplotlib guys deactivated interactive plotting unless you're working on a real (bash, zsh) terminal; and 2) Spyder activates it on their Python terminals so users are not suprised by not being able to see their plots :)  (IPython handles it on its own).

Comment: I forgot to mention that `plt.ion()` needs to be called before `plt.plot`

Comment: @CarlosCordoba It's actually getting better. I put the `plt.ion()` just in the line before `plt.plot()`. However, the graph window pops up and then gone; nothing is plotted on that graph. Do you have any other advice?

Comment: You could try to change your backend, with `matplotlib.use`, e.g. `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` or `matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')`. You need to add this call before `plt.ion()`. HTH :)

Comment: Still does not work. Ok.